# Should I use Vector<char> for string buffer? How do I convert it to String effectively?

Tags: java, buffer

I need to buffer characters from socket, in loop:

```
string buffer;
while(!eof) {
  //read character into buffer

}
```

Now, specifically in java, I have two options. Either use a String and the `+=` operator, which somehow works though there is no operator overloading in java. However, Strings are immutable in Java, which means every time you're modifying a String, you're in fact creating a new one. I think that might be quite ineffective in my case, when many characters may be added sequentially (I'm reading from socket waiting for a delimiter).
Other way would be using some sort of flexible array, such as `List` of `Vector`. This one can accept more characters using `.add` method. But of course, it's a question if it really is faster - in the end, we'll need to convert the data to string anyway.

So: Is `List` more effective than `String` for buffering? And how do I convert `List` to String without `+` operators?

Such conversion is useless:

```
for(int i=0,l=list.size(); i<l; i++) {
    string+=list[i];
}
```

I could be doing the same thing in the receiver loop already...

Comment: You should never use `Vector` in new code unless it's for interoperability with legacy libraries.

Comment: Why is that, I wonder?

Comment: `Vector` has been essentially deprecated for a long time, and the details are explained in the Javadoc. It and `Hashtable` are heavyweight, synchronized implementations that were superseded in Java 1.2.

Comment: Si synchronised `List` (using `synchronized` blocks) is the same thing as `Vector`?

Comment: Also, you can't have collections of primitives. So `Vector<char>` is invalid, but `Vector<Character>`, or even better, `List<Character>`, is valid. As a side note, the only time I see `Vector` objects now is when I'm working with code that's 10 years old.

Comment: Sometimes, kinda. `List` is an interface, not an implementation, and the granularity of synchronization matters. It's usually better to (1) keep collections on-thread when possible, (2) pass unmodifiable (or Guava `Immutable`) views when they're leaving the service that owns them, and (3) use concurrent collections when concurrency really is needed. Even `synchronized` won't save you from some kinds of concurrency clashes.

Comment: @lealand You mean primitives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For buffering a `String`, use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). It has been designed for that.

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
while(!eof) {
  //read character into buffer
  buffer.append(someCharacter);
}
String finalString = buffer.toString();
```

There exists also a `StringBuffer` class, the difference is that the latter one (`StringBuffer`) is synchonized while `StringBuilder` is not.

But in case of multi-threading, I recommend you to use a `StringBuilder` and to synchronize it (read [this article](http://vanillajava.blogspot.de/2013/04/why-synchronized-stringbuffer-was-never.html) from @PeterLawrey).

Comment: Can I loop through string builder using for loop?

Comment: @TomášZato Yes you can. Read the documentation of the class and you will find all the methods that will help you to achieve this task.